# How to add #include in makefile?

Tags: gcc, build, include

I want to build following source: https://bitbucket.org/portix/dwb/src. If I run `make install` I get:

```
In file included from dwbremote.c:19:
./dwbremote.h:22:10: fatal error: 'X11/Xlib.h' file not found
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
         ^
```

So I added `CFLAGS += -I/opt/X11/include`to config.mk. But this didn't fix it. I'm getting the same error.

EDIT: The header to include is at /opt/X11/include/X11/Xlib.h

Comment: check that CFLAGS is used on the build line.

Comment: Where did you add the line?

Comment: I added it right after `CFLAGS += -D__BSD_VISIBLE`

Comment: -I dir
    Add the directory dir to the list of directories to be searched for header files. Directories named by -I are searched before the standard system include directories. If the directory dir is a standard system include directory, the option is ignored to ensure that the default search order for system directories and the special treatment of system headers are not defeated .

Comment: -I-
    Split the include path. Any directories specified with -I options before -I- are searched only for headers requested with #include "file"; they are not searched for #include <file>. If additional directories are specified with -I options after the -I-, those directories are searched for all ‘#include’ directives.

    In addition, -I- inhibits the use of the directory of the current file directory as the first search directory for #include "file". This option has been deprecated.

Comment: Seems like a good place to add it. But try `CFLAGS += -I- -I/opt/X11/include`

Comment: -I- is deprecated. Instead one has to use -iquote, but this doesn't look for `#include <file>`...

Comment: The above extracts are from latest (4.8.1) manuals

Comment: Figured out, make uses 4.2. So I instructed make to use 4.8, but this didn't fix it neither. Still the same error. Even got another error: `/opt/local/include/glib-2.0/glib/ghmac.h:29:23: fatal error: gchecksum.h: No such file or directory
 #include "gchecksum.h"` but gchecksum.h is in /opt/local/include/glib-2.0/glib/. After editing line 29 to `#include "/opt/local/include/glib-2.0/glib/gchecksum.h"` there was no Problem (except for the missing Xlib.h).

Answer (score 0):

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/X11/include
export C_INCLUDE_PATH
```

did the job